# Как проверить сходятся ли логин и пароль которые находятся с списке

Tags: python

код

```
import random
import users

l = input('Введите логин ')
p = input('Введите password : ')

if p == users + p[0]:
    print('True')
    print('True')
elif l != p[0]:
    print(p)
    print('False')
```

вот файл со списками

```
users56802= ['alina03']
users20411= ['big_pinus']
b35878= ['baba']
users14905= ['ya_hz']
```

где переменная это пароль а то что в списке это логин

Как проверить есть ли такой логин и пароль в списке?

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
import users

l = input('Введите логин ')
p = input('Введите password : ')

with open("имя файла", "r") as file:
    flag = False
    for line in file.readlines():
        line = line.rstrip().split("= ['")
        if p == line[0] and l == line[1][:-2]:
            flag = True
    if flag:
        print(True)
    else:
        print(p)
        print(False)
```

Comment: не работает тоже самое почти

Comment: а что именно не так? выдает какую-то ошибку или неправильно считает?

Comment: я тут чуть-чуть исправил. Попробуйте запустить этот код

Answer (score 0):

лучше хранить логины и пароли в файле:

```
users56802=alina03
users20411=big_pinus
b35878=baba
users14905=ya_hz
```

и используйте такой код:

```
def load_users(path):
    users = []
    with open(path) as file:
        for line in file:
            login, password = line.strip().split("=")
            users.append((login, password))
    return users

users = load_users("путь к файлу")
login = input('Введите логин: ')
password = input('Введите пароль: ')

print((login, password) in users)
```

Comment: нет выдает False даже если это правильные данные пользователя